# Multiplayer game/ Where to start

Tags: c#, server, multiplayer

I've recently made a 2 player snake game in c#. Now its working when player on one pc with 2 controllers connected. But what i actually want to implement is that it can be played on 2 pc's which each connect to a server, or 1 other pc connecting to a server on my pc.

My question is does anybody know where to start or what library is best for me to use?

Greetings,

Comment: https://unity3d.com/

Comment: This is not a specific question. Use the search engine of your choice and do some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked a general question so I'll give you a general answer.
First thing you should know, that in order for 2 computers to interact with each other you should create a project for the client side and a project for the server side. then you need to connect the client to the server.
you should choose the type of the host project according to your needs - is it a wpf application? a web application? and so on.

edit:  I suggest you to google "Windows Using SignalR in WinForms and WPF sample" to see an example of a project using signalR as host and web /WinForm / WPF as clients.